# Why doesnt this Flex App draw a simple rectangle?

Tags: apache-flex

the code is straightforward and my Intention should be clear. Still i can get this to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
                mySprite.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x0000FF,1.0);
                mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,50);
                this.addChild(mySprite);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


</s:Application>
```

For this simple a problem, it causes me some trouble! Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var x:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();              
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
mySprite.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x0000FF,1.0);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,50);
x.addChild(mySprite);       
this.addElement(x);
```

Comment: Ok, thx! This works for me. But why do i have to do this? Does it add functionality?

Comment: `Application` in does not implement `addChild` method, so you have to use `addElement`. `addElement` expects an `IVisualElement` which `Sprite` does not extend. So you will have to use `SpriteVisualElement`